# Errors when importing TI PSpice component to Altium

Tags: altium, texas-instruments, pspice

I am trying to import a PSpice model of the [TPS22811](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS22811#support-training) into Altium without success.

What I did:

1. Download the model from the [TI website](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS22811#support-training)
2. In Altium, edit the simulation property of my component and select the *tps22811x_trans.lib* file that was in the downloaded folder.
3. In the dialog shown below,I choose the components model (the other options seem to be sub-circuits used by the component.

   [image: Screenshot of Browse Model dialog]
4. I can correct the pin assignment but there's an error *Unknown model with name "Dbreak"*

   [image: Screenshot of Sim Model dialog]

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong. I looked online for explanations but couldn't find anything useful. My current hypothesis is that Altium only tries to import the file I selected and therefore doesn't have the other subcircuits needed.